# Custom maven plugin fails when mojo extends mojo from different module (no AbstractMojo)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have mutli project with 2 maven plugin modules: base and child (`<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>`). Child depend on base.

Base plugin has single class:

```java
public abstract class BaseMojo extends AbstractMojo {}
```

with POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>plugin-set</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin-set</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>plugin-base</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>my</goalPrefix>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child plugin has single class:

```java
public abstract class ChildMojo extends BaseMojo {}
```

with POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>plugin-set</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin-set</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>plugin-child</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>plugin-set</groupId>
            <artifactId>plugin-base</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>my-child</goalPrefix>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Base compiles correctly, child pass compilation but fails `maven-plugin-plugin:3.4:descriptor`:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.4:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project plugin-child: The API of the mojo scanner is not compatible with this plugin version. Please check the plugin dependencies configured in the POM and ensure the versions match. org/apache/maven/plugin/AbstractMojo: org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo -> [Help 1]

How to build child module?

Both base and child has almost identical pom.xml, child has 1 more dependency: to base

Source: https://github.com/michaldo/mojo-extend-mojo

Comment: Why would you like to extends something different than AbstractMojo for a plugin?

Comment: other standard plugin uses the same approach, to extend a different class than `AbstractMojo`, so it shouldn't be a problem. For instance [the versions maven plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/versions/DisplayParentUpdatesMojo.java) and the [maven relesease plugin](https://github.com/apache/maven-release/blob/trunk/maven-release-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/release/AbstractReleaseMojo.java) do so. Check these links to their github code for some hints.

Comment: 1. I want to reuse BaseMojo protected @Parameters. 2. I want to reuse BaseMojo protected methods. I don't want move methods to POJO (like strategy pattern) because they highly depend on injected stuff like MavenSession.

Comment: @A.DiMatteo in your examples parent class is within givem module, in my case BaseMojo is within different module than ChildMojo. I will clarify issue title

Comment: @A.DiMatteo If you correctly follow the inheritance you will come to AbstractMojo ..Custom plugins should always use AbstractMojo as parent nothing else. A little bit more code would also helpful.

Comment: @khmarbaise indeed, I actually meant it for intermediate super classes, like in this case, the root should then be `AbstractMojo` anyway as you described

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Sure that's true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direct solution to your compilation issue is to remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from the `maven-core` dependency in `plugin-child`.

However, although it will compile after that, there are a lot of changes to be made to your project for it to work.

---

You should have a clear view of what a Mojo is and how it is implemented.

First of all, [a Mojo should comply to a simple contract](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html), which is implementing the [`Mojo`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/Mojo.html) interface.

> Although the requirements on Mojos are minimal by design, there are still a very few requirements that Mojo developers must keep in mind. Basically, these Mojo requirements are embodied by the `org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo` interface, which the Mojo must implement (or else extend its abstract base class counterpart `org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo`).

You can have a hierarchy of abstract classes but the top-most abstract one should inherit from `AbstractMojo` (or implement `Mojo`). Having a common abstract parent class is not uncommon. It is done by a lot of standard Maven plugins, like the `maven-install-plugin`.

What is important to note that the abstract classes are simply there to factor common code from multiple Mojo in a plugin. They do not represent a goal. As such, the `plugin-base` module, which contains your abstract superclass:

- should not be packaged as a `maven-plugin`.
- should not declare an execution of the `maven-plugin-plugin` plugin.

The concrete Mojo is inside `plugin-child` so it is this module that should be packaged as a `maven-plugin`. Since this will be the concrete implementation, it must not be abstract and it can be annotated with `@Mojo` to ease its declaration:

```java
@Mojo(name = "child")
public class ChildMojo extends BaseMojo {
    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    }
}
```

This declares the goal `"child"` for this Mojo.

---

### Sample code

#### `plugin-base`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>plugin-set</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin-set</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>plugin-base</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

with the only class being

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;

public abstract class BaseMojo extends AbstractMojo { }
```

#### `plugin-child`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>plugin-set</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin-set</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>plugin-child</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>plugin-set</groupId>
            <artifactId>plugin-base</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>my-child</goalPrefix>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

with the following Java code:

```java
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;

@Mojo(name = "child")
public class ChildMojo extends BaseMojo {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {

    }

}
```

---

Finally, you can test that this works by depending on this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>plugin-set</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin-child</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>foo</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>child</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you build the test project depending on `plugin-child` then you will correctly see Maven invoking it, on the `install` phase here.

Comment: Big thanks, it was great work and - what more important - it works. (But I don't know why). I feel ungrateful, but I have to said that much of your description does not apply my real case. In real world plugin-base is true plugin with  few concrete mojos. In plugin-child I want reuse BaseMojo logic and I'm happy I don't have to refactor my architecture and all I want put away `provided`